# Two-valued measure is a Dirac measure

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $(X,\mathfrak B)$ be a measurable space such that $\{x\}\in \mathfrak B$ for all $x\in X$, and let $\mu$ be a positive measure on this space such that
$$
  \mu(B) \in\{0,1\} \quad\text{for all }B\in \mathfrak B.
$$
What are the mildest conditions on $(X,\mathfrak B)$ that imply that $\mu =\delta_x$ for some $x\in X$?

It is [known](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/291296/5887) to hold for $\Bbb R$ with a Borel $\sigma$-algebra, and I believe it fairly easy extends to $\Bbb R^n$. I wonder, though, whether it holds at least for locally compact Polish spaces, or perhaps for more general case. I am also interested in examples of spaces where such statement does not hold.

Comment: I guess you mean $\{x\}\in \mathfrak B$. But it is not necessary that singletons are measurable to define Dirac measures.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland: do you mean that such Dirac measures are defined over general atoms?

Comment: For $B\in\mathfrak B$, let $\delta_x(B)=1_{[x\in B]}$. The definition does not need singletons to be measurable.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland: Indeed, thanks for this point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An easy example where it does not hold is an uncountable set endowed with the countable-cocountable $\sigma$-algebra. If one let's $\mu(B)=1$ if $B$ has countable complement and $\mu(B)=0$ otherwise, one gets an example where the measure is not a Dirac measure.

On a countably generated space, every $0-1$-valued measure is  on an atom of the $\sigma$-algebra and hence a Dirac-measure. This is shown in *Borel Spaces* by Rao and Rao, on page 14.  The basic idea is to take a countable sequence $C_1,C_2,\ldots$ of generators and define $D_n=C_n$ if $\mu(C_n)=1$ and $D_n=C_n^c$ otherwise. Then $D=\bigcap_n D_n$ is an atom of the $\sigma$-algebra such that $\mu(D)=1$. If $x\in D$, we have $\delta_x=\mu$.

In particular, the result holds for all Polish spaces.

Comment: Nice! Let me check Rao and Rao

Answer (score 2):

A nice case to consider:

Let $X$ be a completely regular topological space.  The **zero sets** in $X$ are sets of the form $\{x \in X : f(x)=0\}$ where $f : X \to \mathbb R$ is continuous.  The sigma-algebra $\mathcal B$ of **Baire sets** in $X$ is the sigma-algebra generated by the zero sets.  Alternatively, $\mathcal B$ is the smallest sigma-algebra on $X$ such that every continuous real-valued function is $\mathcal B$-measurable.

The condition:

> every (countably-additive) $\{0,1\}$-valued measure on $\mathcal B$ is a Dirac measure

is equivalent to the condition that $X$ is **real-compact**.

References:
Gillman & Jerison, *Rings of Continuous Funtions*.
W. Moran, "Measures and mappings on topological spaces." *Proc. London Math. Soc.* 
 **19** (1969) 493-508.

Comment: The condition is theorem 16 in Hewitt, Linear functionals on spaces of continuous functions, Fund. Math. 37 (1950), 161-189. http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm37/fm37113.pdf