# If a measure only assumes values 0 or 1, is it a Dirac's delta?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on a **metric** space $M$ (with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra). If $\mu(A)\in \{0,1\}$ for all measurable set $A\subset M$, then:

> Is it true that $\mu$ is a Dirac measure?

I think the answer should be negative, but I do not know of a counterexample. There is an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291501/two-valued-measure-is-a-dirac-measure) for the general case where we don't know anything about the topology (metrizable in our case). There you can see also that the result holds for all Polish spaces.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge It is strange to imagine every singleton set having measure zero in your example. I think the "problem" here is that we can only deal with countable nets of sets in the definitions of $\sigma$ algebra and measure. Is there actually a theory which deals with "$\sigma$ algebras" where the closedness under countable unions is replaced by the closedness under unions of nets?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp: I'm not quite sure what you have in mind, but I strongly suspect that theory would become trivial, as every set should be a union of a net of singletons.  (But in the measurable cardinal example, $\sigma$-algebras are irrelevant: $\kappa$ has the discrete metric, so every subset is open, closed, and Borel.)

Comment: @Nate My question was general, not refering to xndrme's question.

Comment: @Nate: Well, you can if ZFC disproves the existence of measurable cardinals... :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Oh, I got my first comment backwards, didn't I.  We don't know whether it's consistent with ZFC that there exists a measurable.  We do know it's consistent that there does *not* exist a measurable.

Comment: @Nate: That is correct.

Comment: Ok, amended comment.  If there exists a [measurable cardinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_cardinal) then the answer is no, since taking $M$ to be such a cardinal with the discrete metric would give a counterexample.  Since it's consistent with ZFC that there don't exist any measurable cardinals, any ZFC counterexample would have to be very far from discrete.

Comment: The result holds for every Lindelof space wth countable pseudo-character,which includes all separable metrizable spaces. Because (1): if every point has a nbhd of measure $0$ then we can cover $M$ with countably many such nbhds, giving $\mu (M)=0.$ But (2): if every nbhd of some point $p$ has measure $1,$ then let $F= \{V_n\}_n$ be an open family with $V_{n+1}\subset V_n$ and  $\cap F=\{p\}.$ Then $1=\mu (V_1)=\mu ( \;\{p\} \cup _n(\;V_n\backslash V_{n+1})\;)\;$  implying $\mu (\{p\})=1.$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As delfonics says, the answer is: yes, if and only if there does not exist a [measurable cardinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_cardinal), and an outline of the proof was given by hot_queen in an answer to a question of mine from 2014 ([Consistency strength of 0-1 valued Borel measures](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/988711/consistency-strength-of-0-1-valued-borel-measures/988915#988915)), which I somehow completely forgot about.  In the meantime, I had written out the argument below, which essentially fills in the details in hot_queen's argument.

One direction is easy.  Suppose $\kappa$ is a measurable cardinal, so that there exists a $\kappa$-additive (in particular, countably additive) $\mu : 2^{\kappa} \to \{0,1\}$ which is not a Dirac mass.  Let $M$ be $\kappa$ equipped with the discrete metric (or for that matter, any other metric that $\kappa$ might happen to admit).  Then $\mu$ (or its restriction to the Borel sets, if we are using a non-discrete metric) is the desired counterexample.

The other direction I found in the paper [1].  The argument, for the current case, goes as follows.

Working in ZFC, suppose there is a metric space $M$ and a 0-1 valued Borel measure $\mu$ which is not a point mass.  Using the axiom of choice, $M$ is in one-to-one correspondence with some cardinal $\kappa$, so we can write $M = \{x_\alpha : \alpha \in \kappa\}$.  (In other words, we have well-ordered $M$.)  Note each $\alpha \in \kappa$ is itself an ordinal.

For every $\alpha$, we have $\mu(\{x_\alpha\})=0$, and $\{x\}$ is a decreasing intersection of the open balls $B(x_\alpha,1/n)$.  So by continuity from above, there is an open ball $B_\alpha$ centered at $x_\alpha$ with $\mu(B_\alpha) = 0$.  Set $H_\alpha = B_\alpha \cap \left( \bigcup_{\beta \in \alpha} B_\beta\right)^c$.  (Some of the $H_\alpha$ might be empty but that is okay.) Note that $H_\alpha$ is the intersection of an open (hence $F_\sigma$) set and a closed set, so $H_\alpha$ is Borel (indeed $F_\sigma$).  And since $H_\alpha \subset B_\alpha$ we have $\mu(H_\alpha) = 0$.  By construction, the $H_\alpha$ are pairwise disjoint, and $\bigcup_{\alpha \in \kappa} H_\alpha = M$.  Now they cite a result of D. Montgomery [2] which asserts that any arbitrary union of the $H_\alpha$ is in fact an $F_\sigma$; in particular it is Borel.

Now define a measure $\nu : 2^{\kappa} \to \{0,1\}$ by $\nu(Y) = \mu\left(\bigcup_{\alpha \in Y} H_\alpha\right)$.  Since $\mu$ is countably additive and the $H_\alpha$ are disjoint, we have that $\nu$ is countably additive.  Moreover, for any $\alpha$ we have $\nu(\{\alpha\}) = \mu(H_\alpha) = 0$, and $\nu(\kappa) = \mu(M) = 1$.  Thus $\kappa$ admits a nontrivial countably additive 0-1 valued measure on all its subsets.

A measurable cardinal $\lambda$ has to have a measure which is not only countably additive but actually $\lambda$-additive, so to finish, we use an argument due to Ulam, mentioned on the Wikipedia page above.  Since we have shown there is a cardinal (namely $\kappa$) with a nontrivial countably additive 0-1 valued measure on all its subsets, there is a minimal cardinal with this property; call it $\kappa_1$ and let $\nu_1 : 2^{\kappa_1} \to \{0,1\}$ be the corresponding countably additive measure.

Suppose $\nu_1$ were not $\kappa_1$-additive; that means there is a collection $\mathcal{C} \subset 2^{\kappa_1}$, having $\kappa_0 := |\mathcal{C}| < \kappa_1$, such that $\mathcal{C}$ consists of pairwise disjoint sets of $\nu_1$-measure zero, and yet $\nu_1\left(\bigcup \mathcal{F}\right) = 1$.  Fix a bijection $\phi : \kappa_0 \to \mathcal{C}$ and define a measure $\nu_0 : 2^{\kappa_0} \to \{0,1\}$ by $\nu_0(B) = \nu_1\left(\bigcup_{\beta \in B} \phi(\beta)\right)$.  Then $\nu_0$ is countably additive; for any $\beta \in \kappa_0$ we have $\nu_0(\{\beta\}) = \nu_1(\phi(\beta)) = 0$ since every set in $\mathcal{C}$ had measure zero; and $\nu_0(\kappa_0) = \nu_1(\bigcup \mathcal{F}) = 1$.  So $\nu_0$ is nontrivial, and this contradicts the minimality of $\kappa_1$.

We have thus shown that $\kappa_1$ is a measurable cardinal.

[1] Marczewski, E.; Sikorski, R.
Measures in non-separable metric spaces.
*Colloquium Math.* **1**, (1948). 133–139. [MR 25548](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=25548)

[2] Montgomery, D. Non-separable metric spaces.  *Fundamenta Mathematicae* **25**, (1935).  527–533.

Note: I wasn't able to find a copy of Montgomery's paper online, and it doesn't seem to be indexed in MathSciNet.  If someone has a copy of this paper, or knows where to find another proof of the result, I would be interested to hear it.  I found a number of other references mentioning this result, so it seems to be fairly well established.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes iff there is no measurable cardinal. For the less trivial direction, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/988711/consistency-strength-of-0-1-valued-borel-measures/988915#988915).

Comment: Heh.  I didn't see your answer until after I posted mine, and I had forgotten about that question of mine.  I didn't fully understand hot_queen's answer at the time, but evidently I've now managed to fill in the details for myself!